# how to select and deselect checkbox using reactive forms in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i have a array of objects with id and value, i am binding to html using reactive forms, when i click on select and deselect all, i dont get any errors nor get the required output. I am not getting where my issue is.

HTML:

```
<div class="col">

    <div class="row row-cols-3" formGroupName="Print">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let print of PrintList;let i = index">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{print .id}}">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{print.id}}">{{print.value}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="SelectDeselectAll" [checked]="isAllChecked()"
                    (change)="checkAll($event)">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="SelectDeselectAll">Select/Deselect All</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
checkAll(ev) {
    this.PrintList.forEach(x => x.id = ev.target.checked)
}

isAllChecked() {
    return this.PrintList && this.PrintList.every(_ => _.id);
}

PrintList = [{ id: 1, value: "flowers" }, { id: 2, value: "fruits" }, { id: 1, value: "cars" }, { id: 1, value: "bikes" },]
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9kyet?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

HTML :

```
<div class="col">

<div class="row row-cols-3" >
    <div class="col" *ngFor="let print of PrintList;let i = index">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{print .id}}" [checked]="print.checked">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{print.id}}">{{print.value}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="SelectDeselectAll" [checked]="all"
                (change)="checkAll($event)">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="SelectDeselectAll">Select/Deselect All</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS :

```
all = false;

checkAll(ev) {
if (!this.all) {
    this.PrintList.forEach(x => x.checked =  true)
    this.isAllChecked()
    } else {
    this.PrintList.forEach(x => x.checked =  false)
    this.isAllChecked()
 }
 }

 isAllChecked() {
   this.all = !this.all
 }

 PrintList = [
   { id: 1, checked: false, value: "flowers" },
   { id: 2, checked: false, value: "fruits" },
   { id: 1, checked: false, value: "cars" },
   { id: 1, checked: false, value: "bikes" },
  ]
 }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wepdop)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that data i am getting PrintList from backend, so i cant add any value or property manually.

Comment: You are welcome,
I think you should clone the data, you are getting from the back, and add the checked state. 
Otherwise how do you consider saving this state, when the user is going to save !?
And when loading the page, do you consider ALWAYS that the check-boxes are unchecked !!

Comment: so here how can i bind the values, manually, with the data got from backend, and yes you are correct, initially it will be empty, but while passing data at time of save or edit, i need to pass the state as well.

Comment: Maybe i dont understand your need, but for me when you get your list from the back, you should loop and add the unchecked state to your objects..
And as you can see in the demo, its working fine

Comment: Hi, in your answer you had manually given checked property to the printList array, but i am not getting whether checked is true or false from backend, i have only the id and value, so now i need to create one more checked key from the array i have got from backend

Comment: Hi, do you agree that the state should be saved somewhere ?!
consider receiving only id and value. what prevents you from looping and adding a default false value in the new checked attribute ?!
Can you describe more the use case, you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, i tried by this way from your answer,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bods7?file=src/app/app.component.ts, but here when i uncheck anyone of them, still i see checked field in unselect/select field